# How to handle multiple same form fields shortway in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I have a table as follows :

```
<table>
  <thead>
     <th>PRODUCT TYPE</th>
     <th>QUANTITY</th>
     <th>WEIGHT</th>
     <th>WEIGHT PRICE</th>
     <th>TOTAL</th>
  </thead>
  <tr>
     <td>DRINKS</td>
     <input type="hidden" name="product[]" value="1" />
     <td><input type="text" name="qty[]" /></td>
     <td>LITER</td>
     <input type="hidden" name="unitPrice[]" value="34.92" />
     <td><input type="text" name="total[]" readonly="readonly" /></td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>DRY FOODS</td>
     <input type="hidden" name="product[]" value="1" />
     <td><input type="text" name="qty[]" /></td>
     <td>KG</td>
     <input type="hidden" name="unitPrice[]" value="16.30" />
     <td><input type="text" name="total[]" readonly="readonly" /></td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>FRESH FOOD</td>
     <input type="hidden" name="product[]" value="1" />
     <td><input type="text" name="qty[]" /></td>
     <td>TON</td>
     <input type="hidden" name="unitPrice[]" value="26.45" />
     <td><input type="text" name="total[]" readonly="readonly" /></td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>SWEET CONFECTIONARY</td>
     <input type="hidden" name="product[]" value="1" />
     <td><input type="text" name="qty[]" /></td>
     <td>TON</td>
     <input type="hidden" name="unitPrice[]" value="65.10" />
     <td><input type="text" name="total[]" readonly="readonly" /></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

So, here is the question :
I want to check input value `qty`, if `qty` is filled then will take the related product value. But, the important things is no required to fill all those fields. Employees can fill one field or more!

Could anybody conduct to me to how can we handle this form with PHP?

Comment: I would suggest you to use unique names for all fields i.e. drinks_qty,drinks_product instead of array to uniquely identify corresponding values.

Comment: @heyanshukla I am afraid of that can't do this way because above form is truncated which is more than thirteen fields available, thanks.

Comment: oh that could be clumpsy. But it seems you have got the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code like this is problematic because the elements of the `product` and `qty` arrays must be kept in sync, but the HTML4 (and HTML5) model for form submission does not say that these `qty` controls have to be [successful](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2). Therefore the browser might choose not to submit their values, which will mess up cross-array indexing.

The cleanest solution would be to explicitly specify the indexes for the arrays in each control's name:

```
  <tr>
     <td>DRINKS</td>
     <input type="hidden" name="product[0]" value="1" />
     <td><input type="text" name="qty[0]" /></td>
     <td>LITER</td>
     <input type="hidden" name="unitPrice[0]" value="34.92" />
     <td><input type="text" name="total[0]" readonly="readonly" /></td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>DRY FOODS</td>
     <input type="hidden" name="product[1]" value="1" />
     <td><input type="text" name="qty[1]" /></td>
     <td>KG</td>
     <input type="hidden" name="unitPrice[1]" value="16.30" />
     <td><input type="text" name="total[1]" readonly="readonly" /></td>
   </tr>
```

This way you can then do

```
foreach ($POST['product'] as $i => $val) {
    if (!empty($POST['qty'][$i])) {
        // the product has a nonzero quantity
    }
}
```

Another option that you might want to consider is this:

```
  <tr>
     <td>DRINKS</td>
     <input type="hidden" name="product[0][product]" value="1" />
     <td><input type="text" name="product[0][qty]" /></td>
     <td>LITER</td>
     <input type="hidden" name="product[0][unitPrice]" value="34.92" />
     <td><input type="text" name="product[0][total]" readonly="readonly" /></td>
   </tr>
```

which would work along with

```
foreach ($POST['product'] as $product) {
    if (!empty($product['qty'])) {
        // the product has a nonzero quantity
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign unique index on array

```
<input type="hidden" name="product[1]" value="1" />
<td><input type="text" name="qty[1]" /></td>
...
<input type="hidden" name="product[2]" value="2" />
<td><input type="text" name="qty[2]" /></td>
```